# How to extract an equal sequence of elements in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, indexing

I have a more specific question, but I haven't found the answer yet. I'm really desperate and would be really happy if someone knew the answer. Thank you in advance for reading ...

I have a list in Python that looks something like this:

> ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]

Now I want to shorten the list so that a block of elements is filtered out that is repeated many times. This means that this list becomes:

> ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]

Does anyone know how this works? The problem: The list can always look different, maybe like this:

> ["b", "y", "e", "b", "y", "e", "b", "y", "e"]

Thank you very much and I would really appreciate your answer!

Comment: Is the first entry always part of the repeating pattern?

Comment: Do you use upper and lower case? I could integrate that if you need that too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be handled quite neatly with a single line function (see below).

```
import re

def shorten(l):
  return list(re.sub(r'^([a-z]+)\1+$',r'\1', ''.join(l)))


l1 = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
l2 = ["b", "y", "e", "b", "y", "e", "b", "y", "e"]

print(shorten(l1))
print(shorten(l2))
```

**Output**

```sh
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
['b', 'y', 'e']
```

**Explanation**

The above solution treats the `list` (`l`) passed at runtime as a `str` of characters in index order.

It makes use of the regex pattern `^([a-z]+)\1+$` to identify whether the whole `str` is made up of a substring that is repeated - i.e. is `l` made up of a single repeating pattern from start to finish?

If this pattern produces a match on the `l` `str`, a `list` representing this repeating pattern (match group 1 (`\1`) is returned.

If no match is made - i.e `l` is not made up entirely of a single repeating pattern - then a `list` identical to `l` passed at runtime is returned.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution:

```
def shorten(lst):
    s = ''.join(lst)
    for i in range(1, int(len(s) / 2) + 1):
        if len(s) % i == 0:
            if s[0: i] * int(len(s) / i) == s:
                return list(s[0: i])
    return list(s)
```

Here are some examples:

```
>>> shorten(['h','e','l','l','o','h','e','l','l','o','h','e','l','l','o'])
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> shorten(['b','y','e','b','y','e'])
['b', 'y', 'e']
>>> shorten(['a','b','c'])
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Thanky you very much! :-)

Comment: Sorry, but this will not pass all scenarios `ls = ["m","o","m","m","y","m","o","m","m","y"];shorten(ls)`